# Apport.log reports "Executable file does not belong to a package, ignoring"

Tags: 12.04

I'm running a tracking program and towards the end of the tracking is done the program just closes. I checked the apport.log and it says "Executable file does not belong to a package, ignoring".

What does this mean and what can i do so the program stops closing? it only does this for certain videos i'm running in the program. The issue is not file size.

It also mentioned apport (pid 2883)

Comment: `apport` is a tool which gathers system information for use when submitting a bug report to Ubuntu Launchpad. Since your program does not belong to a package distributed by Ubuntu there is no point in submitting a bug report to Ubuntu Launchpad, therefore `apport` cannot help. Submit a bug report the project making your program. They will tell you what supplementary info they need and how to get it.

Comment: Is there any other way to find out why the program keeps closing/crashing using terminal?

Comment: Not in general. For help go to the user forum of the program in question, search the bug tracking database of the program etc.